# Multiple Custom Rows UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, custom-cell

I've been searching a lot but didn't find anything useful related to multiple custom rows, I need to create a settings tableView for my app,in which I need to load the rows from xib files,like:

ROW 1 =>> XIB 1.
ROW 2 =>> XIB 2.
ROW 3 =>> XIB 3.
ROW 4 =>> XIB 4.

My present code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell=nil;
    //We use CellType1 xib for certain rows
    if(indexPath.row==0){
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ACell";
        cell =(ACell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if(cell==nil){
            NSArray *nib= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ACell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = (ACell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        //Custom cell with whatever
        //[cell.customLabelA setText:@"myText"]
    }
    //We use CellType2 xib for other rows
    else{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BCell";
        cell =(BCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if(cell==nil){
            NSArray *nib= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = (BCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        //Custom cell with whatever
        //[cell.customLabelB setText:@"myText"]
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you create some custom UITableViewCell classes (.h and .m), as many as you have xib files:
So you could have CellType1 and CellType2 for example.
CellType1.h would look something like

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CellType1 : UITableViewCell

@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UILabel *customLabel;

@end
```

Then you create the xib files, you can use default view type, but then, just remove the view that is automatically created, replace that by a UITableViewCell, and change the class to CellType1. Do the same for CellType2.

Then in your tableViewController, write cellForRow like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell=nil;
//We use CellType1 xib for certain rows
if(indexPath.row==<whatever you want>){
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellType1";
     cell =(CellType1*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if(cell==nil){
        NSArray *nib= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellType1" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (CellType1 *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
      }
      //Custom cell with whatever
      [cell.customLabel setText:@"myText"]
}
//We use CellType2 xib for other rows
else{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellType2";
    cell =(CellType2*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if(cell==nil){
        NSArray *nib= [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CellType2" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (CellType2 *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
      }
      //Custom cell with whatever
      [cell.customLabel setText:@"myText"]
}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with " <whatever you want> "

Comment: You say you want to use multiple Xib, I am guessing xib1 for row n1, xib2 for row n2, etc... So the if/else statement checks on the row index, and based on what you would like to achieve you pick the correct xib in the correct row index

Comment: The main View of my XIB should i change then for UITableViewCells or just resize the view?

Comment: Just delete that view and add a UITableViewCell, then change the type from UITableViewCell to WhateverCustomCell

Comment: Your code still non working for me!Could you help me a little more,i really need this.I'll update my questions and add the code i'm trying now!

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by "not working", you would need to precise if you either have compile errors, or else, what is going on? First think I can tell you is to check that the XIB that contains your tableview has the delegate and datasource outlets to the file owner, which should be the file with the cellForRow code

Comment: You can post things here. Otherwise, I created a quick project that uses a couple of xib for table view cells, right here https://github.com/objectiveapp/MultipleXibTableView

Answer (score 3):

If you're not already familiar with loading a custom cell from a xib, check out the [documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW20). To extend this to multiple custom xibs, you can create each table cell in a separate xib, give it a unique cell identifier, set the table view controller as the file's owner, and connect each cell to the custom cell outlet you define (in the docs, they use `tvCell` as this outlet). Then in your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, you can load the correct xib (or dequeue the correct reuseable cell) by checking which row you're providing a cell for. For example:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier1 = @"MyIdentifier1";
    static NSString *MyIdentifier2 = @"MyIdentifier2";
    static NSString *MyIdentifier3 = @"MyIdentifier3";
    static NSString *MyIdentifier4 = @"MyIdentifier4";

    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    if (row == 0) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifer1];
        if (nil == cell) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableCell1" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = self.tvCell;
            self.tvCell = nil;
        }
    }
    else if (row == 1) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifer2];
        if (nil == cell) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableCell2" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = self.tvCell;
            self.tvCell = nil;
        }
    }
    else if (row == 2) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifer3];
        if (nil == cell) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableCell3" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = self.tvCell;
            self.tvCell = nil;
        }
    }
    else if (row == 4) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifer4];
        if (nil == cell) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableCell4" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = self.tvCell;
            self.tvCell = nil;
        }
    }
    // etc.

    // Do any other custom set up for your cell

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: This method is not working for me. I get a 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'  Thoughts?  I have my ViewController linked to each cell and a custom IBOutlet for each cell made and wired to the cell.