# Multiple columns in tableview ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am working on an app using objective C and Xcode.

For the moment I am using a table view and returning rows with cells containing an image thumb and title. My problem is that now i need to change the layout and for 4 of the cells I need to make them fall on the same row (so each article of the 4 should be 50% width). So basically create 2 columns but only for 4 of the articles. The rest remain on 1 column (full width).

I would add an image but I don't have enough rep points.

I know there is some thing like collection view...but I am not very familiar with that one and I was hoping maybe there's an easier way than redoing the viewcontroller and all the connections I already have created there.

Since I am already using tableview..what's the best way to change the layout to fit what I need now?

Comment: You could add uiview subviews to your cell. But collection view is the way to go if you can spare the time... But you can't have multiple cells next to each other in a row.

Comment: you should go with UIColloctionView. you can find the gud tutorial at http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Comment: Ugh...Ok guys. Thanks. I will go with the collection view then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UICollectionView with flowlayout and variable cell width. There are many tutorials about it out there.
You can also try this library: https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you're trying to do a UICollectionView might not be the best bet. I would create a second type of UITableViewCell for those rows with 4 columns.  This should help [Multiple Custom Rows UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464712/multiple-custom-rows-uitableview)

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at this library:[TSUIKit](https://github.com/Viacheslav-Radchenko/TSUIKit)

If you just want to quickly arrange your data, this would be much easier than trying to wrangle with UICollectionView.