# Custom UITableViewController inside Container View: NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboard

I am trying to insert a custom `UITableViewController` inside a `Container View`. The Container View is placed inside a cell of a static UITableView as shown in the figure below.

[image]

I simply want a method to combine static with dynamic cells in the same screen.

In the `Identity Inspector` when the field *Class* is empty (i.e. a standard UITableViewController) it works showing an empty dynamic table inside the cell. But when I put my custom class name (that extends UITableViewController) in that field I get a `NSInternalInconsistencyException`:

```
[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "Enx-aT-Rum-view-zY2-9U-Z6d" nib but didn't get a UITableView.
```

These are the contents of MyCustomUITableViewController:

```
@implementation MyCustomUITableViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}
@end
```

I have to admit that I still don't understand all the logic behind Container View, but I just want to show only one view inside (not doing any swapping or else).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why you get that error, but it seems like combining static and dynamic cells in this way is the hard way to go (especially since you only have 2 rows). There's nothing you can do with static cell that you can't do with dynamic ones, so I would just use all dynamic cells.

Comment: no 2 is just an example, there might be more. I prefer static for the rest because I have built all the interface in the storyboard, otherwise I had to do it programmatically. Anyway I like your point

Comment: You can still use your interfaces that you built in the storyboard in a dynamic cell; you don't need to do it in code. Just have a unique identifier for each cell that you make, and dequeue which ever one you want based on the indexPath.

Comment: Like the first answer here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464712/multiple-custom-rows-uitableview

Comment: Yes, except without the xib stuff.

Comment: Thanks, I would change it all dynamic, after all it takes less time and code. Anyway I am curious about this issue.

Comment: @rdelmar Last question you said that I can still use Storyboard to design the custom cells, but how can it be done if you don't load the xib/nib for each custom (ex-static) cell?

Comment: When you dequeue a cell with a certain identifier, the table view will get that cell from the storyboard, if there's a cell there with that same identifier. If you've made the cells in the storyboard, there is no xib to load.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed! I learnt a new thing. It was way too easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After banging my head on the desk for so many hours I managed to resolve this.
I had to alloc/init the tableview of MyCustomUITableViewController. I override the `loadView` method of MyCustomUITableViewController:

```
- (void) loadView{
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]init];
}
```

And it is good to go!